# No-S-$B^+$ Theorem like Results

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-states

Classification of multipartite quantum state is an interesting topic in quantum information and there have been many accomplishments in the field. For example, according to [the result](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9811091) of Thapliyal, for tripartite pure state case, there can't be a tripartite pure state with a pair of subsystems in separable marginal state and another pair in PPT (Positive Partial Trace) bound entangle state. This result can be summed up as the following figure. S stands for 'Separable', $B^\pm$ is for 'Bound entangled PPT(NPT)' and D is for 'Distillable'.

[[image: No S-<span class=]$B^+$ Theorem.">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP6ZS.png)

However, is there any progress in ruling out other categories in the catalog given above? What do we know more about tripartite pure states in 2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hayashi and Chen](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.84.012325) did exhaustive classification of tripartite pure states. Let the following letters denote ***S*** : separable, ***P*** : PPT-Entangled, ***R*** :non-PPT reduction and ***N*** : Non-reduction states for each marginal bipartite state. Then, there can be essentially 8 cases: *SSS, SSN, SNN, PNN, RRR, RRN, RNN, NNN*. These are all physically possible quantum states, hence the classification is complete.